# background: url('example.jpg'); Does not work!

Tags: html, css

Okay here's my file structure:

**+WWW**

- index.html
- style.css
- map.jpg

CSS:

```
body {
    background: #000 url('map.jpg') repeat/repeat-x/repeat-y/no-repeat scroll/fixed top/center/bottom/x-%/x-pos left/center/right/y-%/y-pos;
}
```

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

**PROBLEM: map.jpg does not display in any browser (Firefox, Safari) Or TextMate Preview!**

Comment: `map.jpg` isn't displayed, but is the background black?

Comment: Yes thats right, I'm trying Nick Craver's suggestion at the moment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two issues here, first is your CSS being off, it shouldn't have that laundry list of options for each argument left in there:

```
body {
  background: #000 url('map.jpg');
}
```

*Then* your `<body>` doesn't have any content, so it has no dimensions, you'll need to put something in there to see much if any of the image, otherwise the `<body>` element's height is going to be *very* small if not 0, depending on the browser.

Comment: Thank you, you were spot on! this has been bothering me for ages!

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `overflow:hidden;`.  This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

```
body {
    background: #000 url('map.jpg') no-repeat top left;
}
```

The example you used showed all possible option values.

Answer (score 1):

That doesn't look like valid CSS, did you forget to remove the sections you didn't need?

Try something like this:

```
body {
    background:#000 url('map.jpg');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was working on wamp... and it works fine with relative url.

```
body{
    background:url(../image/circle.png) no-repeat; 
}
```

This should definitely work.

Answer (score 0):

Try getting rid of all the extra junk in your css:

```
body {
    background: #000 url('map.jpg');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the image is in the same folder that your css file is in.